# Django modelformset_factory delete modelforms marked for deletion

Tags: django, django-forms

When using modelformset_factory how do you delete objects from the database that get marked for delete in the form?

I create my modelformset_factory like this:

```
ItemFormset = modelformset_factory(Item, ItemModelForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)
qset = Item.objects.filter(pr=pr)
formset = ItemFormset(queryset=qset)
```

When the formset comes back in the POST I get the data like so:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    formset = ItemFormset(request.POST,queryset=qset)
    if  formset.is_valid():
        marked_for_delete = formset.deleted_forms
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for item in instances:
            item.pr = pr
            item.save()
```

When the formset comes back I can get all of the objects marked for delete with `formset.deleted_forms` but I can't figure out how to actually delete them. I've tried looping through each one and deleting each one individually but I get the error: `Item object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None.`

In the template I'm including `{{form.id}}` so each object has it's ID being passed back in the POST.

After calling `instances = formset.save(commit=False)` I can call `formset.deleted_objects` but it's just an empty list: `[]`

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong that would make the objects not get deleted from the database?

Comment: I guess problem is with commit=False. Is "pr" a field of model? If so, you can map it to HiddenInput instead of excuding, ensure it on init() or save() of a formset, and though use usual commiting formset.save()

Comment: ilvar, I tried adding pr to the form in a HiddenField instead of excluding it and I can now call `formset.save()` but it will just save the forms that were committed and not delete the forms marked for deletion from the database. This also results in duplicate database entries for each form that isn't marked for delete (it isn't modifying current entries it just creates new ones, regardless of modifications to current entries new entries will be created)

Comment: Okay setting pr in a hidden field actually worked (I had to remove some old javascript from my previous work around that was breaking it) but I can't figure out how to assign pr to an initial value for empty or extra forms. When I try setting it like this: `formset.initial=[{'pr':pr_pk,'quantity':0}]` quantity gets initialized but not pr.

Comment: You will need to modify formset.data before validating and saving anyway to avoid somebody changing your hidden field value. So you will not need to set it as initial at all (though it should be working regardless of widget type)

Comment: i think calling the formset.save(commit=False) already deleted the items that were marked for deletion. That's why you were getting the None error. I implemented the same use case as yours a while ago, and calling the save(commit=False) and iterating through the instances they did not cause any kind of error even when there are items marked for deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By including all of the fields from the Item model in the ItemModelForm I was able to call `formset.save()` and all models marked for delete in the form get deleted and any models that were modified or added get updated or saved. I include the field 'pr' (a foreign key) as a HiddenInput and initialize it by extending ItemModelForm like so:

```
class EnhancedItemForm(ItemModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EnhancedItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['pr'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        self.fields['pr'].initial = pr
ItemFormset = modelformset_factory(Item, EnhancedItemForm, extra=extra_forms, can_delete=True)
formset = ItemFormset(queryset=qset)
```

Then I was able to handle the post like this:

```
if request.method=="POST":
    formset = ItemFormset(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
        # Save, delete, update ..everything you need in one command:
        instances = formset.save()

        for instance in instances:
            # Make sure the assigned pr hasn't changed
            if instance.pr != pr:
                instance.pr = pr 
                instance.save()
```

Since modelformset_factory accepts a ModelForm class and not an instance of a modelform I had to extend ItemModelForm in the view where I know what I want the pr to be initialized to.

Answer (score 6):

What is confusing you is that `formset.save(commit=False)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Although with `commit=False` set, edited objects are not `save()` d, confusingly, *deleted objects are deleted.*

Therefore, when you loop over `marked_for_delete` after having called `save(commit=False)`, you're getting objects that have been deleted already, hence the `None` for their id's.

Your self-answer is better, more idiomatic Django as it happens; in general, one should just call `formset.save()` and let it default to `commit=True`.  The fact that the `commit=False` case is relatively rare and disused is probably why nobody has fixed the (IMO, buggy) behavior of deleting objects.

(As an aside, I have only observed this behavior in non-transactional/AutoCommit database environments; it might be that with `commit=False` and transactions enabled you get a more robust behavior with respect to deletion.)

P.S. - This behavior has been **changed in Django 1.7**:

> "If you call formset.save(commit=False), objects will not be deleted automatically. You’ll need to call delete() on each of the formset.deleted_objects to actually delete them."

Comment: Note that this behavior has been [changed in Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/#can-delete): "If you call `formset.save(commit=False)`, objects will not be deleted automatically. You’ll need to call `delete()` on each of the `formset.deleted_objects` to actually delete them."