# Delete rows set to be deleted in a formset and duplicates issues

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, formset

I know this question has been asked before (e.g. [Django modelformset_factory delete modelforms marked for deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573698/django-modelformset-factory-delete-modelforms-marked-for-deletion)) but I've tried all the possible solutions, including doing what the official documentation says (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/), and I still cannot delete the forms from my formset.

I have a form which correctly sends POST data with everything I need (including the DELETE instruction).

```
[print(form_links_event.cleaned_data) for form in form_links_event.deleted_forms]
[{'description': 'asdasd', 'link': 'http://www.test.com', 'id': <linksEvent: linksEvent object (25)>, 'DELETE': True}
```

Nevertheless, I need to process the formset before saving all the instances (I need to attach the id of a related model), so I need to call `save(commit=False)`:

```
    instances_links_event = form_links_event.save(commit=False)
    for link in instances_links_event:
            link.event = instance_event
            link.save()
        form_event.save()
        form_links_event.save()
```

Doing so, though, strips the `.deleted_forms` list. In fact:

```
[print(instances_links_event.cleaned_data) for form in instances_links_event.deleted_forms]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'deleted_forms'
```

Therefore I'm stuck in a loop: I cannot save my form directly because I need to attach more data to it first, and in its raw state it has the 'deleted_forms' list. Once I save it with `commit=False` and process with the processing, though, the 'deleted_forms' is not there any more so that I cannot delete those rows set for deletion. Ideally, I'd like to do this:

```
instances_links_event = form_links_event.save(commit=False)

        for link in instances_links_event:
            if (link.delete = True):
                link.delete()
            link.event = instance_event
            link.save()
        form_links_event.save()
```

I'm using Django 3.0.6 with Python 3.7.

**Update**

Even without the commit=False, saving the form with `form_links_event.save()`, I keep having issues: when I save the form in my 'edit page' (i.e. bound form) `save()` saves the existing records again, even if I didn't edit anything, which means I end up with a lot of duplicates. Is something wrong with Django formset or is it just me?

My form:

```
<tbody id='linksEvent_body'>
      {% for formLink in form_links_event.forms %}
          {{formLink.non_field_errors}}
          {{formLink.errors}}

          <trclass="formLink">
              {{ formLink.id }}
              <td>{{formLink.link}}</td>
              <td>{{formLink.description}}{{formLink.DELETE}}</td>
            </tr>

    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been battling with this and working for days on end, trying all sorts of possible parameters and code. I found out that the first time the form is loaded/bound after having saved it, it is not loading the form_management data correctly (i.e. the `-INITIAL` value is not correct and the `extra` blank form is not there) and also the bound data is not always updated. If I try to fix it via JavaScript, for example counting the number of forms displayed and put that number in the `-CURRENT` parameter and that number -1 in the `-INITIAL` or things like that, Django wouldn't like it (the documentation itself says that it is discouraged to tamper with the form management data anyway, which I understand). Once I'd manually refresh the page (by placing the cursor on the address bar and hit enter, *not by hitting ctrl/cmd + R, which would ask me to send the POST data again*), then the form loads correctly and any further edit would nicely save correctly. So, the only way I could find to solve this issue, which looks and sound like a Django inline forms bug to me, is by placing this code in the page containing the form:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

(function()
{
  if( window.localStorage )
  {
    if( !localStorage.getItem('firstLoad') )
    {
      localStorage['firstLoad'] = true;
      window.location=window.location;;
    }
    else
      localStorage.removeItem('firstLoad');
  }
})();

</script>
```

With this code in place everything works like a charm. I hope this will help others who'll face this frustrating issue like myself.

PS: the issue is independent from the `commit=False` instruction. And yes, I declared `@never_cache` in my `view`.